# PowerShell Issue With GUI

Tags: visual-studio, powershell, office365

I am having an issue when setting labels text with a PowerShell command. I am trying to set a label to the size of the mailbox, this is the command I use.

```
$MailBoxSize.Text = Get-Mailbox -Identity $comboBox1.SelectedItem | Get-MailboxStatistics | Select TotalItemSize | ft -HideTableHeader
```

Here is the result I get.

```
Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.FormatStartData Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.GroupStartData Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.FormatEntryData Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.GroupEndData Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.FormatEndData
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should never be capturing the output of a `Format-Table` (or any other `Format-` command). Those commands are used for formatting output, usually to the console. Instead, if you wish to get the value to a property use the `-ExpandProperty` parameter of the `Select-Object` cmdlet. Change your line to read:

```
$MailBoxSize.Text = Get-Mailbox -Identity $comboBox1.SelectedItem | Get-MailboxStatistics | Select -ExpandProperty TotalItemSize
```